# How can I get Sample details by selected sample?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to get sample details depends on selected sample for example
when click on details of sample 1 show its details and sample 2 and so on
I confused how to do that I am new in MVC :

This is the controller code :

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            int UserId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]);
            var samples = _context.hospital_programs.Where(x => x.hospital_id == UserId).ToList();
            return View(samples);
           
        }
```

this is the output image columns in image    Id    Sample Name:

[image]

this is the view code :

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Program.name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.sample.id)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.sample.name)
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
           
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Program.name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.sample.id)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.sample.name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

This is the details controller code :

```
 public ActionResult Details(int id )
        {
          
            int UserId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]);
            var results = _context.RESULTS.Where(r => r.custid == UserId).ToList();
            return View(results);
        }
```

In the details now when I click details for sample 1 it shows results for all samples
how can I update the code to view only sample 1 results or sample 2 results only

where I will add sampleId = selected sample ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :

replace id with sample_id

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.id })

 @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.sample_id })
```